# Why has sentiment analysis been turned off in our LUIS apps?

Tags: sentiment-analysis, sentimentr, azure-language-understanding

Support help needed: A few weeks ago we discovered the shape of the sentiment json object had changed without notice, breaking our code. Now it's breaking again because the entire sentiment object is missing. After investigating in our LUIS app, it turns out the sentiment setting has been turned off in our manage portal, and it is no longer accessible (I can't turn it back on).  What is happening with sentiment?

Comment: This appears to be a support question for Microsoft. Why are you asking it here?

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for responding.  I'm asking it here because this is the only forum available for LUIS currently. Their old UserVoice function seems to have been discontinued. The last email interaction I had with their support team said to use either UserVoice or Stack Overflow. Not at all ideal for support questions, I agree 100%. Just hoping someone from LUIS team sees it.

Comment: So Microsoft is outsourcing user support to strangers on the Internet? Hmmm... "Strangers on the net / Exchanging info / Strangers on the net / Cuz they're so into / Software that might work / Or else it might not, too / Strangers on the net / They're not employees / They just hang around / Don't cost us diddly / Strangers on the net / They might be me or you! / Strangers on the net / There's always one more person / Who's experienced / The same bug you've found / Maybe they have found / A perfect workaround / Just call BillG up today / Maybe he'll take the time to pay..."

Comment: Or..."I've got some time, I'm not busy / I'll log on to SO / Check out some new questions / I'll give it a go! / But any time I wanna get paid / It's the same old answer, y'know? / There ain't no money, honey, see / Just "reputation", no dough / I love answering questions / But they don't pay my bills / But they just hand me a line / And keep the cash for themselves!" (Georgia Satellites, "Keep Your Hands To Yourself")